# Calculating the lengths of a td within subsets of another selection

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am currently stumped on a project I am working on. Using jQuery, I am trying to calculate the length (number of tds) in each div object in an open row. I have a link to my demo.

http://staging.mc.vanderbilt.edu/criss/ui-projects/r4u/073112/lab.html

Clicking on a "Patient Name" opens the row and each "pill" will expand to reveal data. Some "pils" (.results) have multiple data entries. My jQuery selection should count the tds in each .results, then depending on if there are 2 or 3 or more a ".ear" shows up to allow expansion. I don't want the ear to show if there are only 2 tds in the tr.dates row.

I have this functionality working if you click on a "pill" before opening the row. Try the "SPEP" in Patient One row.

I'm relatively new to Jquery so not great at writing complex functions or selections. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count number of tds in tr.dates, you can use something like following

`$(this).find('tr.dates td').length`

assuming $(this) will be the current ".results" div.

So, as per your requirement if above code is equal to <= 2 don't show ".ear".

Some more code to show working thing

```
//Clicked on some button in tr with the class 'pt_row'
$('.pt_row td .name, .info_row td .name').click(function() {
   //Get closest pt_row and iterate through results section in this pt_row.
   $(this).closest('.pt_row').find('.results').each(function() {
      //Count number of tds in the dates
      if ( $(this).find('tr.dates td').length <= 2 ) {
         //We have 2 or less tds. So, don't show ear
         $(this).find('.ear').hide();
      } else {
         //We have more than 2 tds. So, show ear
         $(this).find('.ear').show();
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: If you run that selection on the openrow it counts all the tds in the .results as a group. Somehow I want to split out each .results and count the tds.

Comment: Added some more code to show you to show/hide ears when clicked on patient. Please check.

Comment: That looks good, how do I get that to work in my code? Currently I'm using the click function on tr.pt_row: $('.pt_row td .name, .info_row td .name').click(function() {

Comment: OK, I added that new function. Looks like it's working on a few of the results. The first child .results only have two tds and the ear is still showing (?)

Comment: `resDate.fadeIn('slow')` this line in the else part creating issues. Please let me know what exactly you want to achieve here.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. To best explain what I want to do, try this. Let's use the Patient Three row. Click on the link to load the page and get the default view.

Comment: Oops, Using the Patient Three row, click on each .result "pill" to open them. The "CBC" pill has five tds ib the tr.dates row, so the ear shows to allow expanding to see the other dates. The other .results only have two tds. I want the entire row to open when the Patient name is clicked and the opened .results should look like they do when individually opened. I have an older demo that doesn't have the extra tds to illustrate the idea: http://staging.mc.vanderbilt.edu/criss/ui-projects/r4u/older/

Comment: I am very sorry. I am not able to understand what exactly you want to achieve in this. I tried your older link too. Some more explanation will allow me to help you. :(

Comment: Here's a link to an image I made to help explain. http://staging.mc.vanderbilt.edu/criss/ui-projects/r4u/results_Screen.png

Comment: When I add an alert to this: alert($(this).find("tr.dates td").length) it's giving me the correct lengths of each .results set, but ignores the <=2 and shows the ear regardless of only having 2 tds. Confusing... Ideas?

Comment: As per the image provided, when we click on the patient name, we should not show any ears. and when we click on each pill it should show the ears, if they have more than two tds. am i right?

Comment: Clicking on the Patient Name opens all the "pills"(.results) in the patient row at once, and depending on the number of tds in the tr.dates row the ear will show (more than 2 tds). Clicking on individual "pills" to open and show the ear if needed is working from the initial page view.

Comment: Hi, the given code do exactly the same thing. But I don't know why you are using `resDate.fadeIn('slow')`. In my opinion it is creating problems. I tried to create a chat discussion in stackoverflow. But as per their rules, you need atleast 20 reputation to do participate in chat. :(

Comment: Vanga, I removed that resDate line from my script. I added the alert to the function that tells us how many tds it finds in each .results in the clicked patient row. So it is properly counting but the if else is not filtering correctly.

Comment: Vanga, after messing about with your answer I did get it to work, you answered this properly, I had some issues in my script. Thanks very much!

Comment: [http://chakriv.com/lab/](http://chakriv.com/lab/). Please check here. I tried to update the code and added a demo here.